# How to share my comments, notes etc for my .pdf across multiple devices?

Tags: windows, pdf, sync, android, adobe-reader

I have a Windows laptop and an Android PDA. I'm using Adobe Reader for reading my e-books for both these devices. But I'm also putting comments and notes into them, which are stored only in a single device. How I can put comments from my PDA, but view them from my laptop too (and vice versa)?